# Nintex Workflow 2010 - Make comments mandatory in flexi approval task

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

Does anybody know is it possible to make comment a required field in approval requests ?

In case of rejection comments should be required, without comments no further movement of request can be made.

In case of approval no comments needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

At the Configure Action window of the task, each task outcome ("Aprove", "Reject") has a icon to the left. 
That is the "Edit" button. Click on it to configure the outcome, including setting Comments as Optional, Required or None.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `ApproveReject` Page which has the same aspx UI code to the `ApproveReject.aspx` in the Nintex Application Pages folder under the layouts folder. You can customize the way you wish in this page. You can then attach this page to the approval reject task by a custom content type having the parent content type as the Nintex Task. Selection of this content type while configuring the `ApproveReject` task will call the custom page. A detailed solution can be requested from Nintex Support.